# Wordpress, Timber, print field from WCK custom field in Twig template

Tags: twig, custom-fields, timber

I've created custom fields for a custom post-type using WCK plugin for the fields, and want to get the fields into my Timber Twig template. (I know Timber recommends ACF for this, but am trying WCK first, as this is for a non-profit website and WCK offers things in their free plugin version which ACF doesn't). Here is the relevant line of the php file:

```
$context['home_page_content'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=vopthomepage');
```

and in my twig template I printed:

```
{{ dump(home_page_content) }}
```

The relevant parts (I think?) which I get are:

```
public 'object_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
public 'post_type' => string 'vopthomepage' (length=12)
public 'are_you' => // this is the field group
public 'question_1' => string 'New to the area, looking for a church to join?' (length=46) // this is the field
```

So to get the field I tried `{{ post.question_1 }}` , no joy, so then tried `{{ post.get_field('question_1') }}` I also tried following the advice for ACF with `{{ post.meta('are_you').question_1 }}` but none of these prints anything on the page.

Here's the full dump:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(Timber\Post)[5652]
      public 'ImageClass' => string 'Timber\Image' (length=12)
      public 'PostClass' => string 'Timber\Post' (length=11)
      public 'TermClass' => string 'Timber\Term' (length=11)
      public 'object_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'custom' => 
        array (size=7)
          '_edit_last' => string '1' (length=1)
          '_edit_lock' => string '1583704531:1' (length=12)
          'are_you' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          '_rsc_content_availability' => string 'everyone' (length=8)
          '_rsc_capability' => string '' (length=0)
          'question_1' => string 'New to the area, looking for a church to join?' (length=46)
          'answer_1' => string 'Take a look under the What we do menu, as well as Churches for info and the locations of buildings.' (length=99)
      protected '___content' => null
      protected '_permalink' => null
      protected '_next' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_prev' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_css_class' => null
      public 'id' => int 293
      public 'ID' => int 293
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_content' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_date' => string '2020-03-04 16:42:52' (length=19)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Home page content' (length=17)
      public 'post_type' => string 'vopthomepage' (length=12)
      public 'slug' => string 'help' (length=4)
      protected '__type' => null
      public '_edit_last' => string '1' (length=1)
      public '_edit_lock' => string '1583704531:1' (length=12)
      public 'are_you' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      public '_rsc_content_availability' => string 'everyone' (length=8)
      public '_rsc_capability' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'question_1' => string 'New to the area, looking for a church to join?' (length=46)
      public 'answer_1' => string 'Take a look under the What we do menu, as well as Churches for info and the locations of buildings.' (length=99)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2020-03-04 16:42:52' (length=19)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'help' (length=4)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2020-03-08 21:08:08' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2020-03-08 21:08:08' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'guid' => string 'https://mbp-2.local:5757/?post_type=vopthomepage&#038;p=293' (length=65)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
      public 'status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
```

Comment: Try `{{ home_page_content.question_1 }}`

Comment: No joy with that either sadly - thanks for the try Henrik!

Comment: Could you add the full output of `{{ dump(home_page_content) }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content is in `home_page_content` which is an array of `Timber\Post` objects. To get the content you have to loop through them like so:

```
{% for post in home_page_content  %}
  {{ post.question_1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, if you want just the data from a single, specific element in the array you can do something like

```
{{ home_page_content[0].question_1 }}
```

where the number, in this case 0, refers to which element you want.